# Vba Dictionary Result Don`t Return Correctly

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, excel-udf

I was trying to use dictionary to lookup **value** in `column F`
with **key** in `column C`.
But after the result dont return like I want. It show "0"

Scenario:
1. **key** in `column C` will have mutliple same value
2. I want to sum up all the **value** in `column F` based on **key** and return to `"RAW" Range("C2")`

```
"Sheet2"
```

[image: This database]

```
"RAW"
```

[image: This is where I want to lookup]

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.
Here my code.

```
Option Explicit

Private Lrow As Long
Private oDict As Object

Private Sub CreateDict()
    Dim arrValues As Variant, oKey As Variant, oValue As Variant, i As Long

'Find Master Item List Japan
    Dim Master As Workbook
    Dim t As Workbook

    For Each t In Workbooks
    If Left(t.Name, 16) = "Master Item List" Then
        Set Master = Workbooks(t.Name)
    End If
Next t

    Set oDict = Nothing
    If oDict Is Nothing Then

        Set oDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    End If
    ' Add items to the dictionary
    ' Load values of used range to memory
    arrValues = Master.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Value
    ' Assuming the Key is on first column and Value is on next
    For i = 2 To UBound(arrValues)
        oKey = arrValues(i, 3)
        oValue = arrValues(i, 6)
        If Len(oKey) > 0 Then
            If oDict.Exists(oKey) Then
                ' Append Value to existing key
                oDict(oKey) = oDict(oKey) + oValue
            Else
                ' Add Key and value
                oDict(oKey) = oValue
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetList(ByVal oRange As Range) As Variant
    If oDict Is Nothing Then CreateDict
'    Static oDict As Scripting.Dictionary 'precerved between calls
   If oDict.Exists(oRange.Value) Then
        GetList = oDict.Item(oRange.Value)
'   Else
'         GetList = 0
   End If
End Function
```

Just For Reference.
This is code I use in other workbook and working nicely

```
Option Explicit

Private lRow As Long
Private oDict As Object

Private Sub CreateDict()
    Dim arrValues As Variant, oKey As Variant, oValue As Variant, i As Long

'Find Master Item List Japan
    Dim Master As Workbook
    Dim t As Workbook

    For Each t In Workbooks
    If Left(t.Name, 16) = "Master Item List" Then
        Set Master = Workbooks(t.Name)
    End If
Next t

    Set oDict = Nothing
    If oDict Is Nothing Then

        Set oDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    End If
    ' Add items to the dictionary
    ' Load values of used range to memory
    arrValues = Master.Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Value
    ' Assuming the Key is on first column and Value is on next
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrValues)
        oKey = arrValues(i, 3)
        oValue = arrValues(i, 6)
        If Len(oKey) > 0 Then
            If oDict.Exists(oKey) Then
                ' Append Value to existing key
                oDict.Item(oKey) = oDict.Item(oKey)
            Else
                ' Add Key and value
                oDict.Add oKey, oValue
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Function GetList(ByVal oRange As Range) As Long
    If oDict Is Nothing Then CreateDict
'    Static oDict As Scripting.Dictionary 'precerved between calls
    If oDict.Exists(oRange.Value) Then
        GetList = oDict.Item(oRange.Value)
    Else
        GetList = 0
    End If
End Function
```

**EDIT #1:**
Based on @YowE3k comment I try execute the `GetFile` Function and got the result as picture below.
Not very sure why last one return with 0

Can this is because it have same key already in my dictionary history because in other workbook I use same key.

[image: Result with code]

Comment: If I use the right data the code seems to work for me.  (Except if the key is "MK9J3DLRHSHA001", because that appears to be on the first line of your `UsedRange` and you only populate the dictionary with values starting from the second row of your `UsedRange`.)

Comment: Remember also that a change to "sheet2" will not recalculate any of the cells which contain a formula invoking your function, so if you update sheet2 after the cell is already calculating 0 then it will stay 0.

Comment: i look again in my data. It seen only half of the data return with proper result if I input `Getfile` at `sheet2 Range("H2")` but As I fill down at `sheet2`, other return with 0